# Installing smart switches but instructions don't match my wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to replace a couple switches with smart switches and the instructions provided with the switch I have (TP-Link HS200) don't match my wiring set up 100%. I'm thinking (hoping) I have the right switches, and that I just need to modify the steps a little bit.

Here's my current set up:

- 2 switches sharing the same wiring box. One controls the ceiling fan while the other one controls the ceiling fan LIGHT as well as an outlet on the wall
- 3 bundles of wires coming into the box from somewhere in the wall: upper left, upper right, bottom middle
- Attached to the fan switch (left): 1 copper ground wire, 1 red wire on the side (bottom), 1 black wire on the side (top)
- Attached to the light/outlet switch (right): 1 copper ground wire, 1 red wire (bottom), and TWO black wires (one on top, and the other wrapped around the bottom screw)
- Wires NOT connected to the existing switches: 3 white (neutral?) wires that are twist-capped together and tucked in at the very back of the box

What I've tried to do:

- Fan switch (left): connect black and red wires to the black "live" wires of the smart switch, connect the ground wires, and connect 1 of the white wires to the white wire leading to the upper left corner
- Light/outlet switch (right): connect 1 black wire to 1 black wire on smart switch, connect the other black AND the red to the other black smart switch wire, connect the ground wires, and connect both remaining white wires (upper right and bottom middle) to the neutral    smart switch wire

Results:

- Fan switch doesn't power on at all
- Light/outlet switch is powered on and I was able to set it up on my wifi, BUT it doesn't then the light/outlet on or off at all

Other notes:
The respective switches are the only switches that control the devices, so I don't believe it's a 3-way connection

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Or am I just screwed with my wiring set up and I can't put a smart switch here? Or can I put a smart switch, just not this brand?

This is my first DIY project and my first post on here. Sorry for the long winded post! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Into which cables do each of the wires go? You left that out, very important

Answer (score 1):

I have the same smart switches and it was a breeze to install.  Have you downloaded the Kasa app on your phone?  Once you open the app and select new install, select the diagram that represents the currently installed switch.  After that it gives step by step instructions for proper installation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is US wiring. Since you probably have the common (white) in the box, this is probably not an old house, which is helpful.

I'm guessing you have one cable (maybe from the bottom center) that has a black, white, and copper wire. The black wire is probably going to each of the switches. If so, that's the hot from the breaker. If you disconnect that black wire and turn the breaker back on you should still see power from it when you use your non-contact voltage tester. If that's the case, the other two cables probably go to the fan and outlet. It's also possible the power goes to the fan first and the red is the hot and the black is the switched.

Can you confirm what wires are in each cable and where the wires connect from the switch to the cable? I'll update my answer after.

Comment: White wire in the switch box means nothing. It could be a switch loop, more info or a wiring diphram is needed.

Comment: @EdBeal, you're right, it could even be the hot side or a switched leg, but a shared common is the most likely with what we know, which is why I said "probably." More info is needed.